# python - Clearing memoized function cache after iteration ?

Tags: python, algorithm, caching, igraph, memoization

I have written some code that attempts to approximate the ranking of vertices that minimizes the feedback arc set/ maximizes the maximum acyclic subgraph of a directed graph (at most n=100 nodes) using a series of heuristics and algorithms mentioned in this paper Sorting Heuristics for the Feedback Arc
Set Problem by Franz J. Brandenburg and Kathrin Hanauer, University of Passau Germany.

The data that gets read in is an adjacency matrix, that gets converted to an igraph.Graph instance.

I am memoizing the cost function and the sifting function. The arguments to both functions are a rank (tuple containing an ordering of vertices) and edgeList (tuple containing tuples representing edges).

Since I am processing multiple instances at a time and the vertices are represented by integers, I need to make sure that the cache of both functions gets cleared out after processing one instance (graph) and I am not entirely sure this is happening. I have found some memoize timed cache implementations and memoize with _remove methods, although i keep getting the same results.

This was for a project that was due earlier today (12/06/2015 5:00 pm) but being as stubborn as I am, I kept working on it and want to make sure Im using the memoize method correctly.

I attach the relevant code I have used:

```
@memoize
def cost(rank, edgeList):
    rankMap = {} 
    for i in range(len(rank)):
        rankMap[rank[i]] = i
    cost = 0
    for edge in edgeList:
        u, v = edge[0], edge[1]
        if rankMap[u] < rankMap[v]:
            cost += 1
    return cost

class memoize:

    """Gives the class it's core functionality."""
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self._memos:
            self._memos[args] = self._function(*args)
        return self._memos[args]

    def __init__(self, function):
        self._memos = {}
        self._function = function

    """Removes all memos. This is particularly useful if something that     affects the output has changed."""
    def remove_memos(self):
        self._memos = {}

def alg_star(algorithm, costFunc, graph, rank):
    edgeList = tuple([i.tuple for i in graph.es()])
    while True:
        rankPrime = rank
        rank = algorithm(tuple(rank), edgeList)
        if costFunc(tuple(rank), edgeList) <= costFunc(tuple(rankPrime), edgeList):
            break
    return rankPrime


@memoize
def sifting(rank, edgeList):
    copyRank = list(rank)
    rankValues = {}
    for node in rank:
        rankValues[tuple(copyRank)] = cost(tuple(copyRank), edgeList)
        for i in range(1,len(copyRank)):
            copyRank[i-1], copyRank[i] = copyRank[i], copyRank[i-1]
            rankValues[tuple(copyRank)] = cost(tuple(copyRank), edgeList)
        copyRank = list(argMax(rankValues))
    return copyRank

# def evaluateFAS(fileNameList):
rankings = []
for fileName in fileList:
print fileName
adjMatrix, incoming, outgoing = fasGraph(fileName)
instance = igraph.Graph.Adjacency(adjMatrix.tolist())
pre_process(instance)
# rank = kss200(instance)
rank = fasAlg(adjMatrix, incoming, outgoing)
rank = alg_star(sifting, cost, instance, rank)
rank = np.array(rank) + 1
rankings.append(rank)
cost.remove_memos() #not sure if working properly
sifting.remove_memos() # not sure if working properly
# return rankings
```

Any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me. Lets give it a little test drive

```
class memoize:

    """Gives the class it's core functionality."""
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self._memos:
            self._memos[args] = self._function(*args)
        return self._memos[args]

    def __init__(self, function):
        self._memos = {}
        self._function = function

    """Removes all memos. This is particularly useful if something that     affects the output has changed."""
    def remove_memos(self):
        self._memos = {}


@memoize
def f(x, y):
    print('f')
    return x + y

@memoize
def g(x, y):
    print('g')
    return x * y

print(f(2,3))
print(f(2,3))
print(g(2,3))
print(g(2,3))
print(f._memos)
print(g._memos)
f.remove_memos()
g.remove_memos()
print(f._memos)
print(g._memos)
```

output

```
f
5
5
g
6
6
{(2, 3): 5}
{(2, 3): 6}
{}
{}
```

Why do you think it wasn't working properly?

Comment: Just being paranoid i guess. I wasnt (am) entirely sure how memoization works in terms of global/local environment. And since I was getting the same output as before i placed the two lines with the "not sure if it works" coment, I thought I didnt memoize/cleared correctly. Also I wasnt sure how to do a simple test, thank you very much for the response.